# Why is a Symmetric Relation also Transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

A relation R on set A is as follows:

R = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)}

R is symmetric!

But WHY is R Transitive?

Comment: Assume that $x R y$ and $yRz$. What does that tell you? Can you prove that $x R z$?

Comment: You should be more clear on your doubts. Why should it be non transitive?

Comment: @Crostul - The answer for this is that it is transitive and symmetric. I don't understand why it is transitive, i thought for transitive you need (1,2) (2,1) and then (1,1) but there is no 1,2 or 2,1

Answer (score 1):

Many symmetric relations are not transitive; for example: A lives within one mile of B.  So your title would make more sense if instead of "Why is a symmetric relation transitive?" it said "Why is this symmetric relation transitive?".

It is transitive because it lacks any opportunity not to be transitive: you would need to find $a, b, c$ such that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ but $a\not\sim c$ in order to have a relation that is not transitive.  The only way you can say $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ with **this** relation is if $a=b=c$.  And in that case $a\sim c$ holds.

Comment: if a relation lacks (a,b) and (b,c) for all elements does it automatically make it Transitive?

Comment: @RandomMath Note that $a,b,c$ need not necessarily be distinct. $a=b=c=1$ works in your $R$, for example, since $1\sim 1$.

Comment: If there are no elements $a,b,c$ such that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $\sim$ is transitive.  This is an instance of "vacuous truth", whereby a statement may be true even if uninformative.  For example, suppose I ask whether all cell phones in the classroom have been shut off.  If there happen to be no cell phones in the classroom, then the answer is "yes".  This last example illustrates one way in which the concept of vacuous truth is practical. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

All you need for transitivity is
$$(a,b)\in R, (b,c) \in R \Rightarrow (a,c)\in R$$
But $(a,b)\in R$ implies $a=b$ (*why?*), so $a=b=c$ and thus transitivity follows immediately from reflexivity.

Comment: What is the best way to tell if a=b=c? When it comes to the equals, i get confused

Comment: @RandomMath The only relations defined by $R$ are $(1,1), (2,2)$ and $(3,3)$. All of these satisfy $(a,b)\in R \Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove it, we are wanted to suppose that $(a,b), (b,c) \in R$. Our goal is to show that $(a,c) \in R$. However, For any different element $a, b, c \in A$. So $(a,b), (b,c) \in R$ cannot hold, and this shows the transitive is true.

Comment: So if R ={1,1} would that be transitive?

Comment: @RandomMath $R = \{(1,1)\}$ (note the extra parentheses) is indeed transitive.

Comment: It is! indeed!!!